# How to handle orientation change with web view in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel

Working on a library at the moment.
The library has a method for example:

```
private fun showWebView(context: Context, tokenProvider: TokenProvider, url: String,): Result {
    val fragment = WebViewFragment(tokenProvider, context, url)

    return fragment.showWithResult()
}
```

Which will call this method in the fragment:

```
fun showWithResult(): Result {
    show(fragmentActivity.supportFragmentManager, TAG)
    return Result.SHOWN
}
```

The issue I am facing is when we launch this DialogFragment, which shows a fullscreen WebView, when I rotate the screen, it crashes. This is due to the Fragment not having a nonnull constructor.
The fragment needs the params it has, as it does some method calls based on what happens in the WebView using the TokenProvider etc.

setRetainInstance is deprecated, and it suggests using a ViewModel. I am not sure how to implement a ViewModel in this way.
I would have to make multiple things parcelable to pass them to the fragment as part of the newInstance method and set them on the ViewModel there unless there is another way.

Would appreciate some recommendations on how best to approach this.

Thanks!

Comment: A ViewModel is just a shared in-memory object, you can store whatever data you like in there - I might be missing something, but you shouldn't need to make anything Parcelable. So long as you're using the parent Activity's VM, everything running in that Activity can use that VM object to store data and communicate with each other. So maybe have an initialisation function that stores your data in the VM (whatever you're passing into the Fragment's constructor) and *then* creates the Fragment. That Fragment can then fetch the data during onCreate (it's attached to the Activity then)

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks for the reply. So to clarify, the library method just gets passed the activity context. The calling app will pass that so we don't actually have access to it's view model, which makes it trickier. I thought maybe making a viewmodel and attaching to the fragment but couldn't figure out how. Hopefully that clarified it a bit, any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Oh I missed that this is a library (you might want to add that to the question title/tags, I don't have much experience with writing libraries so maybe someone has specific advice around it). Yeah you could just try using the `WebViewFragment`'s VM instead - use `ViewModelProvider(owner).get(WebViewFragment::class.java)` to grab the VM associated with that fragment. Usually you'd use the current Activity or Fragment for the `ViewModelStoreOwner`, but I don't know if what you're doing complicates things there. You could implement it yourself, but a singleton object might be easier at that point

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks I will modify the question. I have tried using a viewmodel, but there's 2 parts I'm not sure of. How do I pass objects to the fragment that I need on creation, like the tokenProvider, and when the activity is destroyed on rotation, the viewmodel seems like it's destroyed and I can't get it back so I'm pretty lost on how I should proceed. Can I have a viewmodel on the library that I can attach to the context (which would be the passed activity) to link then some how?

Comment: One of the main purposes of ViewModels is to survive Activity recreation without having to do anything special, so you shouldn't need to do anything different. Your Fragment should just grab the appropriate VM as usual, either with `ViewModelProvider().get()` or one of the Kotlin extension functions like `by activityViewModels()`. Then you can access the data stored in that VM (like your tokenProvider) during onCreate or whatever. To store that data in the first place, you need to access the same VM object in the same scope before you display the Fragment.

Comment: I added an answer to avoid spamming the comments - also that one up there where I said `get(WebViewFragment::class.java)` is wrong, you need to get the **shared object** there i.e. `get(SomeViewModel::class.java)`. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: @cactustictacs thanks for the replies! I will reply on your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer just so I have more space to type and the comment thread was getting long - this is the general approach I'm talking about:

```
private fun showWebView(context: Context, tokenProvider: TokenProvider, url: String,): Result {
    // first create your basic Fragment - you could store the url in its
    // arguments if you want, but I'll assume it's data in the VM for simplicity
    val fragment = WebViewFragment()

    // now get the ViewModel you're going to store the data on
    // Maybe you'd need to pass the Activity as the store owner instead,
    // depends what you're doing
    val model = ViewModelProvider(fragment).get(YourViewModel::class.java)

    // set the data
    model.tokenProvider = tokenProvider
    model.url = url

    // now you can display your Fragment
    return fragment.showWithResult()
}
```

Then in your fragment, in whichever lifecycle function you need to do the setup  (you're attached to the parent Activity in `onCreate` and later, if you need that) - maybe you're using `onCreateDialog`:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // grab the same VM instance you did before, using the same owner
    // since we used the Fragment before, we can use 'this'
    val model = ViewModelProvider(this).get(YourViewModel::class.java)

    // now do whatever setup you need by reading the data stored in the VM
    setUpWebView(model.tokenProvider)
    ...
}
```

That's the basic workflow with a ViewModel - I used the explicit `ViewModelProvider` access to make it clear what store owner you're using in both cases (I made a mistake in the comments earlier, sorry) but you can also use the Kotlin extension functions too, so long as you're aware which scope you're accessing when you use them. [More info in here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-apis#java).

---

But like I said, I haven't done this with a library before, and I'm not sure if it throws up any complications, siloing off the library's VM stores but allowing the `DialogFragment` to access the main app's stores when it's being displayed. You'd have to do some logging and check what instances you're getting.

Depending on your situation, it might be easier to just create a basic singleton object in your app:

```
object WebViewSetup {
    var tokenProvider: TokenProvider? = null
    var url: String? = null
}
```

and then just set the data on that when launching the WebView / read from it when initialising the Fragment, in the same way as before. This may or may not bring its own complications (like if you're trying to hold a `Context`) so it really depends on what you're doing. If the VM works for you, it's a good option!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!
Your solution ended up working. I had to change to use the activity instead of the fragment for retrieving the viewModel. I never thought to actually assign the params of the viewModel in the library calling class like you did there.

Thanks again, super chuffed to have it working. All the best!

Comment: @Ayohaych no worries, glad you got it working! Yeah you need to make sure you're using the correct VM store owner, so you're definitely fetching the same shared object. For a Fragment, generally you'll grab the parent Activity's copy of a VM, which also allows you to communicate with other Fragments in that Activity (since they're all using the same VM object - it's a good way to pass data). If you grab the Fragment's own copy of a VM, that's sort of "private" and you'd use that for stuff only that Fragment has any interest in, since other things can't access it easily

Comment: Yeah I think its where I was going wrong in the past was trying to get some instance of the fragments view model instead of using the activity. Just need to do some testing now to make sure its working okay. Thanks again

Comment: only thing I would be curious about is, on orientation change and restoring of the state, it doesn't seem like the web view client gets restored. I would have to reset the webview client everytime or should that get restored?

Comment: @Ayohaych where are you holding a reference to it? If everything holding a reference to it is getting destroyed, that `WebViewClient` will be garbage collected, same as anything else. That's why you need to put stuff in the `ViewModel`, because that outlives everything else. So your `Fragment` setup code needs to pull that `WebViewClient` instance from wherever you're storing it (or create a new one and store it, if it's not created yet). If you're not already doing that, you must be constructing a new one every time, right? (You might need to store the `WebView` too, to maintain the display)

Comment: Yeah so the way I was doing it was I had 2 methods in the VM, saveState and restoreState, which I passed in the webview and called the saveState and restoreState methods on it. Then when the fragment was recreated I called the restoreState on the VM. However it never worked. Now I just save the URL to VM and reload it. This has a downside that any form data which was filled in on the web page is lost. I don't know is there a way to retain any inputted information on the web page when we rotate. For example entering my name in a text field and having it still be there

Comment: @Ayohaych it's been a while since I did any WebView stuff, but the idea is you call `saveState` on your WebView, and stick the result of *that* in your Fragment's `savedInstanceState` `Bundle`. Then do the reverse when restoring state. But that won't store "display data" anymore, according to the docs - which I assume means things like content, scroll position, entered data? The general "web content" section has a section on handling config changes (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/webapps/webview#handling-changes) and the recommendation there seems to be preventing them

Comment: maybe whatever way I was saving it wasn't using the bundle correctly. I will look into it. Thanks!